# Проверка пунктуации в двух предложениях

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Мне нужно проверить эти два предложения на пунктуацию.

**Вот поэтому(,) Артем является моим самым лучшим другом детства.

Но иногда(,) он был не прочь повеселиться.**

Нужны ли запятые в отмеченных местах?

Comment: Виталий, Вы можете объяснить, что Вас заставило предположить, что эти запятые нужны?

Comment: Правила. Но я все же сомневаюсь в правильности расстановки

Comment: Какие правила тут действуют, по-Вашему?

Comment: Перед словом "поэтому" ставится запятая, из-за сложно подчиненного предложения.

Comment: Иногда - не ставится запятая, т.к простое предложение

Comment: Нет здесь причин для постановки запятых, это обычные обстоятельства, не обороты.

Comment: Людмила, то есть вы хотите сказать, что нигде запятых не нужно?

Comment: Виталий, *Поэтому* может быть союзным словом в  сложноподчиненном предложении (СПП), например:  Стало темно, поэтому зажгли лампу. Но запятая ставится перед словом поэтому,а не после него. У вас от  СПП осталась только вторая часть, а в ней запятые не нужны.

Comment: М_Г, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Основной признак сложного предложения - это две предикативные основы (подлежащее + сказуемое). Артем является другом - в этом предложение одна основа,значит, это простое предложение. А в начале предложения могут быть разные слова: наречия,  частицы, присоединительные союзы и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вот поэтому Артем является моим самым лучшим другом детства.**

Слово *поэтому* может быть союзным словом в сложном предложении с двумя основами, например: Стало темно, поэтому зажгли лампу. Но и тут запятая ставится перед словом *поэтому*, а не после него. У вас от сложного предложения осталась только вторая часть, это простое предложение (одна основа: "Артем является другом"), а в нем запятые не нужны.

**Но иногда он был не прочь повеселиться.**

Простое предложение (одна основа: "он был не прочь повеселиться"). Повеселиться (*когда*?) иногда. Иногда — обстоятельство времени. Никаких запятых.

Comment: Стало темно, поэтому зажгли лампу. И почему же это  СПП, а не БСП? Не бывает союзных слов в СПП с придаточным следствия, там только союз ТАК ЧТО.

Comment: @Ксения, на нашем форуме эта тема обсуждалась.

Comment: И что решили? Это СПП?

Comment: @М_Г И  еще вопрос. вы хотите объяснить, почему предложение является простым или сложным, но такое объяснение нужно начинать с определения основы: одна основа - простое, две основы - сложное.

Comment: @Ксения,  "Нужно начинать с определения основы". Согласен. Так в чем Ваш вопрос?

Comment: @Ксения, Нашел обсуждение слова "поэтому" на Грамоте: http://gramota.ru/forum/spravka/63517/ Нет единого мнения.

Comment: А Вы как считаете? Союз, союзное слово, местоименное наречие?

Comment: @Ксения, Интуитивно мне ближе СПП и союзное слово. Но я бы оставил это академикам решать.

Comment: @Ксения, Интуитивно мне ближе СПП и союзное слово. Но я бы оставил это академикам решать. Есть модная теория о том, что не надо разбираться , где ССП, где СПП, где БСП — все это спложные предложения и баста. Тогда и спор о том, союзное слово у вас в предложении или местоименное наречие, теряет актуальность.

Comment: Разобраться легко, нужны только четкие определения, и они есть в вузовских учебниках, но до школ и пользователей никак не дойдут. Сочинительная союзная связь в ССП, подчинительная союзная в СПП, бессоюзная в БСП.  "Поэтому" не может быть союзом, так как это не служебное, а знаменательное слово (оно является членом предложения). "Поэтому" не может быть союзным словом в СПП, так как там нет местоименной (взаимной)  связи,  когда и в главном, и в придаточном предложении есть связующие элементы  (указательное слово - союзное слово). И ЭТО ВСЁ. Разве сложно?